# Auto generate bounding polygon for a given image

Tags: svg, polygon, detection

I'am trying to create a list of points which is intended to describe the bounding polygon of the given image as closely as possible. The polygons will be used to calculate collisions between two graphics. So they have to be accurate and small (in terms of the points per polygon) at the same time.

My base images (e.g. PNG) are always monochrome pictures with a however shaped black "spot" in the middle. I have tried to achieve this by using the `autotrace` cli tool which converts my image to svg. I am currently parsing the paths within the svg to get the coordinates of the bounding polygon.

This solution works but is quite inefficient. The points generated by the autotrace command shown below are to accurate.

```
autotrace -output-format svg --corner-threshold=360 --remove-adjacent-corners  --despeckle-level=20 -output-file sample.svg sample.gif
```

For the example shape attached to this post this generates ~800 points, where - theoretically-  4 would be sufficient (one at each "corner").

[image: Example shape]

As I am not interpolating curves at runtime, the resulting svg has to consist of lines only.

How to get a proper bounding polygon that is accurate enough but has got a small footprint?

Comment: Given your example - a bounding polygon for the supplied image would have considerably more than 4 vertices. However, if you are really expecting only 4 vertices then perhaps you're after the bounding rectangle?

Comment: Nope, I'am not looking for the bounding box which would be quite simple. The four points mentioned earlier are meant as: 1 on each tip plus one on the notch as shown by the red dots. If you connect those 4 dots the shape describes the form pretty well.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree. Those 4 dots you've added don't describe the shape very well at all. At best they are an approximation, but you did state ... "I'am trying to create a list of points which is intended to describe the bounding polygon of the given image as closely as possible"

Comment: I have the same or very similar need. It's so tedious, manually producing and testing out lists of points and triangles for the purposes of creating bounding polygons for collision detection purposes.  How do other people do this?  I guess most of them are probably working with 3D modeling tools and game engines and so on, and the game engines do collision detection for them, and work with geometry that is exported from a 3D modeling tool.  Come to think of it, I bet I could use a 3D modeling tool to create 2D models, and.. basically use those models in my stuff..